# Meaning of 'jumps across' in sentence

Tags: meaning, verbs, prepositions, sentence

The sentence is,

> The English teacher jumps across the room with a large stick.

Does it mean the English teacher really jumped from one position to another position?

Comment: Can you provide some context for the sentence? What precedes and follows this sentence?

Comment: The paragraph suggests that the teacher is very bad and angry. He beats his student with that stick.

Comment: Then I would say the answer to your question is "Yes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One finds it difficult to say, given so little context.  It could mean that the English teacher actually jumped from one point to another.  But more frequently [hyperbolic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbolic) sentences like that are figurative; it is likely to mean "moves rapidly", as often expressed with verb "springs" instead of "jumps".